# How to check if the connection to MySql through RMySql persists or not?

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi

I have connected to a mysql database through the RMySQL package using this statement:

```
con<-dbConnect(drv=RMySQL::MySQL(max.con=1,fetch.default.rec=500),host="host",dbname="dbname",password="psswd",user="user"))
```

So far no issues. When I check:

```
>class(con)
[1] "MySQLConnection"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RMySQL"
```

After an hour I used the following statement:

```
dbGetQuery(conn=con,"show tables")
```

and I got an error:

```
Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
```

However, If I check this statement:

```
dbListConnections(drv=RMySQL::MySQL())
```

It gives:

```
[[1]]
<MySQLConnection:0,21>
```

When I try:

```
dbDisconnect(conn=con)
```

I get the same error:

```
Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle
```

Then I removed the connection object:

```
rm(con)
```

When I tried to connect again using dbConnect(), I got this error:

```
con<-dbConnect(drv=RMySQL::MySQL(max.con=1,fetch.default.rec=500),host="host",dbname="dbname",password="psswd",user="user"))
Error in .local(drv, ...): Cannot allocate a new connection: 1 connections already opened
```

I know that the dbListConnections() call returns an empty list when there is no connection to the database. But in this case does not return an empty list.

Is the **corrupted connection handle** a different **state** of the connection than the **disconnected state**?

OR

The connection has timed out?

What is the best approach to keep a check if the connection to DB is still working?

Comment: Keeping a connection open for that long is a very, VERY serious error. You should close a connection as soon as you finish using it. The reason is that any transactions, locks that were acquired while the connection is open persist until it's closed, leading to serious performance degradation. Just close the connection and open it *ONLY* when needed

Comment: To put it another way, if you did that on a database used by others, you'd get an urgent phone call from the DBAs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay. Thank you for pointing out the mistake. So I should assume that it is an implementation mistake on my part rather than an issue with the package?

Comment: Yes. In fact, removal of idle connections is the standard behavior since v 6.2. [Check this link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/connection-pooling/). Through connection pooling, the driver will clean up and cache the connections you close so they are available the next time you want to open a connection. This means that the cost of opening a connection is minimal if there are connections available in the pool

Answer (score 4):

You still might need to close the connection with [`dbDisconnect(con)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbDisconnect) instead of `rm(con)` to free the internal connection handle and allow a new connection. The latter only removes a "pointer" to the connection object (so that you cannot access this object anymore via `con`), but it still exists physically until [garbage collection](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/gc).

You could check if the connection is valid via `dbIsValid(con)`, or use a simple `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT 1")`. I'd be interested to know if the former detects a disconnect on your system, there's a [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI/issues/122) around this topic.

Comment: I did try dbDisconnect(con) as mentioned in the question. But it throws the corrupted connection handle error. I am going to check the dbIsValid(con) command tomorrow.

Comment: I established a connection, queried the DB and then disconnected it using dbDisconnect(con). After that if I perform, dbIsValid(con) : I get the corrupt connection handle error. But using the same (con) I am able to reconnect again to the db. I have not checked this for a connection kept alive for a longer duration as I have changed my code as per the suggestions from @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Have you looked into `pool`? Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/pool) and here's an [intro article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html). It does all of this boilerplate work for you... It basically allows you to not worry about what @Panagiotis Kanavos hinted at when he wrote "Keeping a connection open for that long is a very, VERY serious error." It'll make sure you're not doing that, while giving you the exact same semantics.